# How to use multiple pre_get_posts on functions.php?

Tags: php, wordpress

I will try to explain as good as I can (sorry if my english is bad, this is not my native):

I have two custom post types and two custom post type archive pages for each of them.

To filter posts which are displayed in those pages I created two different functions inside functions.php file with "pre_get_posts" function as you can see in code below.

**My functions.php:**

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts'); 
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ) {

some code here...

}

add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts_2');
function my_pre_get_posts_2( $query ) {

some code here...

}
```

The problem is that second function (my_pre_get_posts_2) is overwriting first one (my_pre_get_posts) and first function is not working on custom post type archive page.

I tried to use `is_post_type_archive( 'custom_post_type' )` but first function still is not working.

What I need to do to assign first function only to specific custom post type archive page and not to call it on any other pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered [in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_post_type_archive). You should use a single callback:

```
function my_pre_get_posts( $query ){
    if ( is_post_type_archive('cpt_1') ) {
        // Do stuff for a custom post type
    } elseif ( is_post_type_archive('cpt_2') ) {
        // Do stuff for a different custom post type
    }
}
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'my_pre_get_posts');
```

Comment: You're welcome. It's important to note that you don't actually *need* one callback. You can use two, but you'll need to add a conditional to each.

Comment: If you have 2 more `pre_get_posts` callbacks, I'm assuming you would still use the condition `is_main_query`. For example, in the first callback it would look like `$query->is_main_query() && $query->is_home()`. In the second callback, it could be `$query->is_main_query() && $query->is_front_page()` and so on. Is there a benefit of having a single callback versus more discrete ones?